# What is the alternate command of grep -A for Solaris?

Tags: linux, shell, solaris, glassfish-3

I am trying to grep few exception details from a server log file.
I have tried this:

```
cat server.log | grep -A10 exception
```

so that i can get exception details.
But server response is:

```
grep: illegal option -- A
```

Is there any alternate  in Solaris for above command ? Please help.

Comment: Which version of Solaris?  You may have `/usr/gnu/bin/grep` or `/usr/sfw/bin/grep` available with the GNU grep that has the -A option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same behavior as `grep -A` can be achieved with awk:

```
awk -v A=10 '/exception/{f=A+1} f{print;f--}' server.log
```

The above prints the match and the ten lines following it, just like `grep -A10 exception server.log`.  The value of `A` can be changed as you like.

#### Example

Consider this sample file:

```
$ cat server.log
a
b
c
exception
1
2
3
4
5
```

With A set to 3, the following is the output:

```
$ awk -v A=3 '/exception/{f=A+1} f{print;f--}' server.log
exception
1
2
3
```

#### Special note for SunOS/Solaris

The native awk on Sun/Solaris is notoriously bug-filled.  In its place, use `nawk` or
better yet `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`  or `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk`.  For example:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -v A=10 '/exception/{f=A+1} f{print;f--}' server.log
```

#### Simulating grep's behavior with multiple files

When given multiple file names, grep's output changes to:

```
$ grep -A3 exception server.log server.log
server.log:exception
server.log-1
server.log-2
server.log-3
--
server.log:exception
server.log-1
server.log-2
server.log-3
```

We can emulate this with awk as well (this may required GNU awk):

```
$ awk -v A=3 '/exception/{f=A+1;if(x)print"---";x=1} f{print FILENAME (f==A+1?":":"-") $0;f--}' server.log server.log
server.log:exception
server.log-1
server.log-2
server.log-3
---
server.log:exception
server.log-1
server.log-2
server.log-3
```

Comment: `grep -A` adds some formatting when grepping multiple files and/or printing line numbers; to disambiguate matches from context, a colon is printed after the file name or line number on matching lines, while context lines get a dash instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `-A` context (and useful) option doesn't seem to be part of the Solaris `grep`, according to the [man](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/grep-1.html).

You could try to recompile the [grep source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git).

If you know enough Perl or python a command like `grep -A 10 exception files` wouldn't take many lines.

Here is a Perl example that works like `cat file | grepa.pl exception` showing 10 lines of context after the keyword has been found (or `./grepa.pl` in the current dir).

**grepa.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$CONTEXT = 10;

$search = $ARGV[0] or die "need search term!";
$n = 0;

while(<STDIN>) {
     $n = $CONTEXT+1 if (/$search/);
     if ($n) {
          print;
          $n--;
     }
}
```

The program could be improved to have `$CONTEXT` given as parameter, or search any regex.

Comment: It doesn't really matter here, but compiling the regex before the loop would be a good idea if you had multiple patterns, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed as well for this:

To print next 10 lines including the line containing matching pattern.

```
sed -n '/pattern/{p;n;p;n;p;n;p;n;p;n;}/' file_name
```

To print next 10 lines excluding the line containing matching pattern.

```
sed -n '/pattern/{n;p;n;p;n;p;n;p;n;p;}/' file_name
```

You can play around with the number of lines to display by adding or deleting n's and p's. If the number is big, awk is a better choice but sed approach is easy.